# SSH Tunneling Depth

Tags: unix, ssh

I know you can perform actions through an SSH like this:

```
ssh remote@dyndns.org 'your actions'
```

But I am wondering, if you have a network with other local computers on the other end of the remote connection can you perform an `ssh` to those computers and perform actions. Would it look like this:

```
ssh remote@dyndns.org 'ssh computer_local 'your actions''
```

Is this possible? If so how deep can you go, can you connect to an inner network and go three deep?

Comment: whay are we closing this with no comments?

Comment: @MattBall Why did you vote to close this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I've done this. There's no limit really. You don't need quotes in the command. For example:

```
    ssh user1@host1 ssh user2@host2 ssh user3@host3 env
```

In order for this work, though, you need passwordless logon in the entire chain.

Comment: Tahnks, that is awesome.